# A lot of messages with subject "Attachment" and label "Trash"

Tags: gmail-api

I very confused with one thing. 
I create a message and attach three files to it.
Then i call method **Users.messages: list** from Gmail API and see one my message with label "Draft" and 3 messages with subject "Attachment" and label "Trash".

Questions:

Why did i get my attachments as message in trash ?

How can i filter such message/attachment when retrieve message list from Gmail Api ?

Comment: I use  "API Explorer" on https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Comment: you pointed to **Users.messages.attachments: get**
But i ned to call list of all messages with Users.messages: list

Comment: Could you provide your request and response code?

Comment: I wrote no code, i just used API Explorer on GMail api pages. Response code is confidential information, but you can easily replay this strange behavior.