# Message with subject "Attachment" appears with "TRASH" label

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

If I create draft with any attachment on web version of gmail, I can see that has been created message with subject "Attachment" and label "TRASH". It's invisible on web, but I getting this message when I call gmail api to get messages with label "trash". It's completely the same messaege as any general message (same fields, no "hidden" indicator). 
Anyone knows how it can be filtered as gmail do?

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928257/a-lot-of-messages-with-subject-attachment-and-label-trash) but without answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your expected outcome? How do you think it should work?

Comment: @noogui I want to find a way to detect such messages and hide them. It works ok from my point of view, but Gmail don't show such messages, so I want to implement the same behaviour. But I don't know how to do it atm :)